# Why do you specify a pool in a deployment job in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I find it hard to grasp the concept of deployment jobs and environments in Azure Pipelines. From what I understand, a `deployment job` is a sequence of steps to deploy your application to a specific environment, hence the `environment` field.

If so, why is there also a `pool` definition for agent pool for that job definition?

#### EDIT

What bothers me is that, from what I understand, an *Environment* is a collection of resources that you can run your application on. So you'll define some for **dev**, some for **stage**, **prod**, etc. So you want to run the job on these targets. So why do we need to specify an agent pool to run the deployment job on? Shouldn't it run on the resources that belong to the specified environment?

#### EDIT

Take this pipeline definition for example:

```
jobs:
  # Track deployments on the environment.
- deployment: DeployWeb
  displayName: deploy Web App
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  # Creates an environment if it doesn't exist.
  environment: 
     name: 'Stage'
     resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
    runOnce:
      preDeploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo "Hello"
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self 
        - script: echo my first deployment
```

I have an environment called "Stage" with one virtual machine on it.

[image]

When I run it, I can see both jobs run on my VM

[image]

The agent pool specified is NOT USED at all.

However, if I target another environment with no machines on it, it will run on Azure Pipelines vm

[image]

Comment: As this isn't really a programming question, it would probably be a better fit for [devops.se].

Answer (score 0):

The `environment` field denotes the target environment to where your artifact is deployed. There are commonly multiple environments like through which the artifacts flow, for example `development` -> `test` -> `production`. Azure DevOps uses this field to keep track of what versions are deployed to what environment etc, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments):

> An environment is **a collection of resources that you can target with
> deployments from a pipeline**. Typical examples of environment names are
> Dev, Test, QA, Staging, and Production.

The `pool` is a reference to the agent pool. The agent is the machine executing the logic inside the job. For example, a deployment job might have several logical steps, such as scripts, file copying etc. All this logic is executed on the agent that comes from the agent pool. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents):

> To build your code or deploy your software using Azure Pipelines, you
> need at least one agent. As you add more code and people, you'll
> eventually need more.
>
> When your pipeline runs, the system begins one or more jobs. **An agent
> is computing infrastructure with installed agent software that runs
> one job at a time.**

Comment: From experience, once I specify an `environment` (assuming this environment has at least one resource on it) the whole job will be executed there. So what's the point in specifying a pool agent?

Comment: No, the `pool` and `environment` are two unrelated concepts. The job logic is executed on a `pool agent`. `Environments` are an abstract concept denoting the target environment. The deployment job itself does **not** run on the `environment`, it runs its logic on an `agent` from the `pool`, which prepares or installs things in the `environment`

Comment: you can go and try it. Create one or more VM resources on an environment, run a job targeting this environment, and you'll see that it runs on ALL the VMs that belong to that environment

Comment: It will run **on** the _pool agent_ **for** all VM's that belong to that _environment_. Could you please share a yaml defintion of the pipeline you want me to try, it might clear some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you specify a pool in a deployment job in Azure Pipelines?

That because the environment is a collection of **resources** that you can target with deployments from a pipeline.

In other words, it is like the machine that hosts our private agent, but it can now be a virtual environment, like K8s, VM and so on.

When we specify an environment, it only provide us one virtual environment(You can think of it as a machine). However, there is no agent installed on these virtual environments for us to run the pipeline, so we need to specify an agent to run the pipeline.

For example, we execute our pipeline in our local machine, we still need to create our private agent, otherwise, we only have the target environment, but there is no agent that hosts the pipeline running.

Comment: please refer to the edit of the question.

Comment: @YoavKlein, you may not understand my answer. Indeed, an Environment is a collection of resources that you can run your application on, but if the Environment not install the agent, how to run the application with azure pipeline? Just like I said, if you run pipeline on your local machine, but the machine do not have any private agent install, how did you run the pipeline? We could not just select the machine name in the agent pool option.

Comment: I understand that if you didn't create any resource in an environment you can't use it, since it's not there. My question is: what is the reason behind the possibility of running a "deployment job" against an environment with no resources defined - but rather running it on the agent pool ? My question is not technical

Comment: @YoavKlein, If the environment with no resources defined. This has no practical meaning, the job is still running it on the agent pool directly, but the pipeline will have Environments benefits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is confusing and you are right.
I think they have made this a "feature" to cater for scenarios where you want to box deployments under "environments" but you can't actually run the deployment logic in the environment itself because it doesn't have any resources on which logic can be run.

Imagine this scenario, you have an FTP site for staging, and another for prod. The FTP site is provided by a thrid party hosting provider so you can't jump on and install a devops agent, you just get the FTP access credentials from them.

You want to set up a CI/CD pipeline and use a deployment job to deploy your site to "Staging" and "Prod" via FTP.

With this "Feature" you can run your FTP deployment job to deploy to "Staging" and "Prod" and the job can run on an agent pool agent and run some FTP task to deploy the files to the coorrect FTP site.

Now you can look at the environment page and have a better understanding over the deployment history of your app for those two environments, evenn though they have no resources.

Those saying that an empty environment (i.e no resources) is meaningless are not really seeming to understand the feature as a whole because there is some value in being able to cater for this scenario, all being it is failry limited (at present) as I have outlined.

However what is confusing about this "feature" is it is not clear / explicit over where the job logic will run when looking at the yaml - for example as you said, if you set the agent pool you would expect the job logic to run on that agent, but if the env has VM resources it doesn't - it gets ignored. This is a poor design imho. It would be better if microsoft made it so that if you set the pool the job ran on that agent pool regardless, if you wanted it to run on the resources in the environment, you could just omit the pool. If you don't specify a pool and the env has no resources the job could either fail telling yoou to specify a pool or register some resources, or alternatively the job could run on a default pool provided by microsoft if that is the typical behaviour.